# "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'zclip'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, zclip

I'm trying to imprement the Zclip to my project, but it's always give me the title error.
Already search a lot, find a lot of 'solutions' but this error simply don't go away.

Heres my code:
JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>

$("a#click_expremed").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).zclip({
  path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
  copy: function () {
    return $('#expremed').text();
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="generated black" style='display:inline-block;' id='click_expremed'>
<span id="expremed"> Some Random text</span> </a>
```

Please, if someone know some fix, say me!

Comment: Once I had the exact same error, but with `jCarouselLite` plugin.  What I did to solve it was include the JS file at the end of the HTML, right before the end of the body tag.  Hope it helps.

Comment: What happens when you put the URL http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js into your browser?  Does it spit out a file, or give you a 404 error?

Comment: @SableFoste Nupe, it's show me the script.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding your jQuery code with `$(document).on("ready", (function(){ //your code here });` ?

Comment: @SableFoste Yes, it's inside a 'document.ready'.

Comment: Also, if makes any difference, the target anchor is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.  Please see the following fiddle, ignoring the cross domain error in the console.log:  http://jsfiddle.net/AQrNs/6/

Repeating exactly your code, minus the link:

```
$("a#click_expremed").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).zclip({
  path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
  copy: function () {
    return $('#expremed').text();
  }
});
```

With HTML of:

```
<a href="#" class="generated black" style='display:inline-block;' id='click_expremed'>
  <span id="expremed"> Some Random text</span> 
</a>
```

I can duplicate your error only when I delete the External Resource of the fiddle.  I believe the issue is that somehow, your zclip file is not being loaded.  As  @juanchopx2 mentioned, the script calls should be included in the `<header>` of your HTML, not the `<body>`.  Most of the time, this doesn't matter, but semantically it is correct, and may be causing your issue.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, I said wrong when I replied @juanchopx2, my JS content are all on head part. And I already tried to get a code from JSFiddle which as workin perfectly and when I paste in a page and runs localy (Xampp) it's still works but wasn't get the content to copy to clipboard anymore, and when I tried to join to my main project, it stopped to work.